# \subsubsection not appearing on document

Tags: sectioning

My subsection titles are not appearing on the PDF rendering of my TEX document.

Please help. 
Thank you

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{24pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{24pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{24pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\author{John Brown}
\affiliation{Brown University}

\title{TITLE HERE}
\shorttitle{SHORTTITLE HERE}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\pagebreak

\section{Introduction}

\section{Research Data}
\subsection{Behavioural Evidence}
A 2013 study by Albouy et al. analysed the behaviour of amusics compared to controls.
\subsection{Electrophisiological Evidence}
According to Peretz et al. amusics don't show N2 and P3.
\subsection{Neuroimaging Data}
\subsubsection*{Voxel-based morphometry (VBM) Data}
Using VBM, cortical thickness of both control subjects and amusics was measured. 

\bibliography{References.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: \documentclass[doc,apacite]{apa6}

Comment: @user60367, then please update your question (or can't you do that when you are new at the site? Welcome by the way)

Comment: The `titlesec` package seems to conflict with your document class.

Comment: apa6 is one of the strange classes I will never understand. If not absolutely necessary, I would not use it

Comment: try set tocdepth to the appropriate level you require

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `titlesec` package is not compatible with most non-standard document classes; in particular, is not compatible with `apa6`. You can achieve the desired change in formatting redefining the sectional units as defined by the class.

Here are the original definitions for `\section`, `\subsection`, and `\subsubsection` in `apa6.cls`

```
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
    {\b@level@one@skip}{\e@level@one@skip}%
    {\centering\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
    {\b@level@two@skip}{\e@level@two@skip}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\parindent}%
    {0\baselineskip \@plus 0.2ex \@minus 0.2ex}%
    {-1em}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\addperi}}
```

The second, third and fourth arguments of `titlesec`'s `\titlespacing` command correspond, respectively to the fifth, sixth and seventh arguments of `\@startsection`, so you can make your modifications there, as the following example illustrates using the values that you were using in your example code. I also redefined `\addperi` so besides adding a period, a space is also added (since you are using values that will make the text to follow right after the titles):

```
\documentclass{apa6}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\addperi}[1]{#1.~}

\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection {section}{1}{24pt}%
    {\parskip}{-\parskip}%
    {\centering\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\addperi}}

\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{24pt}%
    {\parskip}{-\parskip}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\addperi}}

\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{24pt}%
    {\parskip}%
    {-\parskip}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\addperi}}
\makeatother

\author{John Brown}
\affiliation{Brown University}

\title{TITLE HERE}
\shorttitle{SHORTTITLE HERE}


\begin{document}

\section{A test section}
Test text
\subsection{A test subsection}
Test text
\subsubsection{A test subsubsection}
Test text

\end{document}
```

[image]